# Preloader doesn't stop on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I'm trying to stop a preloader after the page has been loaded.

Let's say we take the preloader below.

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #eaecfa;
}

.loader {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ce4233;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.loader::before, .loader::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #ce4233;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: load .7s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
          animation: load .7s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.loader::before {
  top: 0;
}
.loader::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 235px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
  }
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 235px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Why does the following JS code work, i.e. I get the alert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    alert("This can run");
  });
  })
```

And the same code with a changed line doesn't stop the preloader?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("loader").remove();
  });
  })
```

I'm a complete newbie to web development, however have tried many other answers here, but I cannot get any of them to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `.` at the `$("loader").remove()` :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(".loader").remove();
  });
  })
```